# Refreshing Image in JLabel doesnt work

Tags: java, image, swing, refresh, jlabel

Hi, I have a problem with refreshing an image, added to `JLabel`. It is something like control light which give us information about status online/offline. When we start application and server is on, its going to call this method and change light to green. We can of course click button "go offline" and make it offline all time. Then the light is red. By now everything works fine, but when we click "go online", the program is online but the image is still red.    In every place its called by the same method. Just this light doesn't work, because connecting and disconnecting works fine.

I give you some code:

Method which just change the image:

```
 public void changeLight(String name){
    BufferedImage imgtmp;
    try {
        System.out.println("CHANGE LIGHT: "+name);
        imgtmp = ImageIO.read(new File(name));
        panelMenuOnline.remove(panelMenuOnlineLight);
        panelMenuOnlineLight = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(imgtmp));
        panelMenuOnline.add(panelMenuOnlineLight);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

button definition in the same class:

```
panelMenuButOn = new Guzik("GO ONLINE"){
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if(!Pang.game.online){
                Pang.game.haveToBeOffline = false;
                if(Client.checkConnection()) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,
                            "Successfully connected");
                    Pang.game.online=true;
                    changeLight(imgGREEN);

                } else {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,
                            "Connection refused");
                }
            } else {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,
                        "Successfully disconnected");
                setText("GO ONLINE");
                Pang.game.haveToBeOffline = true;
                Pang.game.online=false;
                changeLight(imgRED);

            }
        }
    };
```

and i have also thread which (if I don't made him offline) testing connection and change control light:

```
public void run() {
    while(true){
        Pang.game.online=Client.checkConnection();
        if(Pang.game.online){
            Pang.game.frame.panelMenuButOn.setText("GO OFFLINE");
            Pang.game.frame.changeLight(Pang.game.frame.imgGREEN);
        } else {
            Pang.game.frame.panelMenuButOn.setText("GO ONLINE");
            Pang.game.frame.changeLight(Pang.game.frame.imgRED);
        }
        //System.out.println("Checked = "+Pang.game.online);
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace(); 
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're not just changing the Icon shown by the JLabel, but changing JLabels entirely, and I recommend that you don't do that. Instead,...

- Read in your Images and create your ImageIcons on program creation, not each time you need to change the light.
- Use just *one* JLabel to hold the icon.
- When you want to change the light, call a method that doesn't require a String. A boolean might do well if the light is only in 2 states. And then swap out ImageIcons in the one JLabel. Don't go swapping JLabels mid program when this is not needed.
- Code lines like this: `Pang.game.frame.panelMenuButOn.setText("GO OFFLINE");`, suggest that you are using static fields and methods. If so, you will want to re-configure your program so that it does not do this, so that it uses instance methods and fields for most everything.
- I agree with Ross Drew -- all your Swing calls should be made on the Swing Event Dispatch Thread (or EDT) only. 1+ to his answer.

---

For example,

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.EnumMap;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class StopLightApp extends JPanel {
   private static final String IMG_PATH = "http://urbannight.files.wordpress.com/2012/09/"
         + "red-orange-green-traffic-lights.jpg?w=300&h=240";
   private static final int PAD = 13;
   private JLabel stopLightLabel = new JLabel();
   private EnumMap<LightColor, Icon> lightIconMap = new EnumMap<LightColor, Icon>(
         LightColor.class);
   private LightColor lightColor = LightColor.RED;

   public StopLightApp() throws IOException {
      URL stopLightImgUrl = new URL(IMG_PATH);
      BufferedImage stopLightImg = ImageIO.read(stopLightImgUrl);
      for (int i = 0; i < LightColor.values().length; i++) {
         BufferedImage smlLightImg = specializedForThisImageGetSubImage(
               stopLightImg, i);
         Icon smlIcon = new ImageIcon(smlLightImg);
         lightIconMap.put(LightColor.values()[i], smlIcon);
      }
      add(stopLightLabel);
      stopLightLabel.setIcon(lightIconMap.get(lightColor));
      stopLightLabel.setText(lightColor.getName());
      stopLightLabel.setHorizontalTextPosition(SwingConstants.CENTER);
      stopLightLabel.setVerticalTextPosition(SwingConstants.BOTTOM);
      setBackground(Color.white);
      setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(10, 60, 10, 60));
   }

   private BufferedImage specializedForThisImageGetSubImage(
         BufferedImage stopLightImg, int i) {
      int x = PAD + (i * (stopLightImg.getWidth() - 2 * PAD)) / 3;
      int y = PAD;
      int w = (stopLightImg.getWidth() - 2 * PAD) / 3;
      int h = stopLightImg.getHeight() - 2 * PAD;
      BufferedImage smlLightImg = stopLightImg.getSubimage(x, y, w, h);
      return smlLightImg;
   }

   public void setLightColor(LightColor lightColor) {
      this.lightColor = lightColor;
      stopLightLabel.setIcon(lightIconMap.get(lightColor));
      stopLightLabel.setText(lightColor.getName());
   }

   private static void createAndShowGui() {
      try {
         final StopLightApp stopLight = new StopLightApp();
         JFrame frame = new JFrame("Stop Light App");
         frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
         frame.getContentPane().add(stopLight);
         frame.pack();
         frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
         frame.setVisible(true);
         int delay = 1000;
         new Timer(delay, new ActionListener() {
            int index = 0;

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
               index++;
               index %= LightColor.values().length;
               stopLight.setLightColor(LightColor.values()[index]);
            }
         }).start();
      } catch (IOException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowGui();
         }
      });
   }
}

enum LightColor {
   RED("Red"), YELLOW("Yellow"), GREEN("Green");
   private String name;

   private LightColor(String name) {
      this.name = name;
   }

   public String getName() {
      return name;
   }
}
```

Which creates a light that can change:

[image: red light]  [image: yellow light] [image: green light]

Comment: ... but I can upvote yours, IMHO it is excellent answer for this question.

Comment: i was looking for that solution but i can not find how to swap icon in label, because i think i have to remove one Icon and add another?

Comment: @user3233685: please see my code example above. All you need to do is call `setIcon(Icon icon)` on the JLabel to swap icons, that's it!

Comment: thank you for that solution ;)) everything works fine!

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels : Everytime, I look your answers, I learn something new about the language. Exceptional work :-)